# Notepad++ plugin for Prolog support?

Tags: text-editor, notepad++

My current favorite thing to program in is [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), but the default version does not support Prolog, which I am now learning in one of my classes. Is there a plugin for that?

Alternatively, can you recommend another text editor (I don't use IDEs that much) that supports the Prolog language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of Notepad++ Prolog plugins available in the [User Defined Language Files](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/user-defined-language-system/) page of the [Notepad++ Community User Manual](https://npp-user-manual.org/).